# how to call a method in another method with return?

Tags: c#

I am relatively new to c# programming. I am working with Forms and I want to print a value in text box which is not working. I am getting an error "not all code paths return a value"

```
public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    double res = test();
    tbox.Text = res.ToString();

}

public double test()
{
    if (Cbtest.Checked == false)
    {
        return 10 + 5.1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Assume that `Cbtest.Checked` is true, and what are you returning then?

Comment: What behavior are you seeing? What error are you getting?

Comment: what you want to print in textbox if Cbtest.Checked == true

Comment: `test()` doesn't return an explicit value on all control points. If you did that in C++ then the compiler might eat your cat.

Comment: To expand on comment by @Bathsheba, you haven't accounted for a situation where `Dbtest.Checked == true` so the code will do nothing if you tick that CheckBox and press the button

Comment: your code will  not compile

Comment: Just to be mentioned: `Cbtest.Checked` can be `null` as well ;)

Comment: You need to include an errors you get when compiling or running your code in future questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with the `test` method, you need to consider the `Cbtest.Checked==true` condition as well otherwise your code will raise error as *"not all code paths return a value"*, so better you change the signature as like the following:

```
public double test()
{
    if (!Cbtest.Checked)
    {
        return 10 + 5.1;
    }
    return 0.0; // or some other values
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to return something if your box is checked:

```
public double test()
{
    if (Cbtest.Checked == false)
    {
        return 10 + 5.1;
    }
    return -1.0;
}
```

Your method always needs to have a return value, even if you know that condition will be `false`, compiler doesn't.

Comment: Doesn't C# have a "boxed" `double` type; you could return "null" if the box is not checked?

Comment: You should be careful what you say with these types of question... you will no doubt get picked apart with even the slightest of incorrect statement. For example, it doesn't always need a return value

Comment: @Bathsheba, it's a `double` and not `double?` ... thus it's not possible to return `null`

Comment: Indeed, but isn't there a type that's a bit like a double but can also hold `null` (cf. `Double` in Java)?

Comment: @Bathsheba, NO. not in C#. If you want primitive type like double or int to hold null then declare them as nullable saying `double?` but in this case OP simply returning double

Comment: C# is above my pay grade. I'm just a humble C and C++ programmer. I'll get me coat.